# Disabling flutter_map package rotation in Flutter

Tags: flutter, fluttermap

How do you disable the rotation of the map in [flutter_map](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_map)?

Comment: https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_map/latest/flutter_map.plugin_api/InteractiveFlag-class.html

Comment: This worked. If you wish to get a correct answer please post an Answer instead of a comment. 

Thank you :) Or I can answer it by myself and give you the credits.

Comment: yes, write a self answer then

Answer (score 44, accepted):

As written by @pskink the answer is to use the `InteractiveFlag` provided by `flutter_map` in such a way

```
MapOptions(
    minZoom: 11.0,
    maxZoom: 17.0,
    center: LatLng(lat, lng),
    interactiveFlags: InteractiveFlag.pinchZoom | InteractiveFlag.drag,
    zoom: 13.0,
  ),
```

By doing this, you can ensure that only `pinchZoom` and `drag` actions are allowed in your map.

Answer (score 11):

This is better:

```
MapOptions (  
    interactiveFlags: InteractiveFlag.all & ~InteractiveFlag.rotate,
 )
```

Answer (score 3):

MapOptions (
interactiveFlags: InteractiveFlag.all & ~InteractiveFlag.rotate,
)

I have used this in the past

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the API Documentation, there is a class **MultiFingerGesture**. This looks like it controls the gestures on the Widget, and there is an option to only allow **PinchMove**, or **PinchZoom**. The default looks like it's the **all** option. If you change the Map's property that equates to this class, and change to either **PinchMove**, or **PinchZoom** then it should work. Please review the class here:

https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_map/latest/flutter_map.plugin_api/MultiFingerGesture-class.html

Comment: I've never used this package, so I'm taking this only from the author's api documentation. If this does not give you any compile time errors, then go ahead. Please try this, and let me know

Comment: Nah it did not work. I added the `.pichZoom` option and it still rotates.

Comment: then I would post an issue on the github repository. Contact the Author, and they can help